# How the metadata API works(Deployment) when we change a field data type to formula?

Tags: metadata-api, formula-field

I have a scenario where I have to change some of the field's data type to the formula type. My question here is how the metadata API works when we deploy/ migrate the changed fields?

1. Will, it allows the fields to be deployed as a formula field?
2. Do we need to create separate formula fields and need to change the references in the environment to deploy the changes + Destruct the existing fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will, it allows the fields to be deployed as a formula field?

No, you can't do things in the Metadata API that the UI wouldn't allow. Changing a field from non-formula to formula would cause compilation errors in Apex, Workflow, Flows, etc.

> Do we need to create separate formula fields and need to change the references in the environment to deploy the changes + Destruct the existing fields?

Yes, you would need potentially multiple deployments in order to complete the process.

Comment: so in this case we might lose the data in the existing fields?

Comment: @Hariprasath You'd lose the data anyways if you could convert a non-formula to a formula. You don't necessarily need to delete the old field if you don't want to.